# Scheduled Jobs stopped working

Tags: wordpress, scheduled-reminders, stripe, scheduled-job

CiviCRM v 5.66.0
Wordpress v 6.3.2
PHP V 8.1.25

Yesterday, all scheduled jobs were working fine but today Scheduled Reminders and Stripe: Cleanup  have both stopped working with the following error logs

Stripe:  Stripe: Cleanup    Finished execution of Stripe: Cleanup with result: Failure, Error message: datefmt_create: invalid locale: U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR

Scheduled Reminders:  Send Scheduled Reminders  Finished execution of Send Scheduled Reminders with result: Failure, Error message: datefmt_create: invalid locale: U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR

Both have the same error message.  Could anyone please help me in discovering what may have caused these errors?

There's nothing in ConfigAndLog   All other jobs are working fine so CRON job seems OK

Answer (score 2):

FURTHER UPDATE:

CiviCRM 5.67.0 solves the various issues that I found. Thanks very much for fixing.

Chris

UPDATE:  This was originally a "me too" comment but now is a partial answer.

The problem occurs here:

wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/log/php-8.1-strftime.php

The problem seems to be that PHP 8.1.25 (and 8.2.12 I think) throw an exception if $locale is invalid for IntlDateFormatter()
https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/12561

For me, $locale was coming through as "C" which is invalid.
For now, I've added in this extra line 104:

$locale = "en_GB";

This gets the Send Scheduled Reminders job working - and hopefully some other things that I'm told weren't working, such as some event booking.

I did previously try the CiviCRM 5.66.2 release but that didn't help.

Is there some setting within CiviCRM (or the server) which I need to set to get the $locale coming through properly?
I'd recommend that the code be updated so that it can cope with a duff $locale.

Chris

---

I am seeing the same Send Scheduled Reminders job error on a live site since yesterday morning on CiviCRM 5.65.2. And I get the same error on a test site when I try today to upgrade from 5.65.2 to 5.66.1:

datefmt_create invalid locale: U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR

Test site error report:
WordPress version 6.3.2
Active theme: Twenty Seventeen (version 3.3)
Current plugin: CiviCRM (version 5.66.1)
PHP version 8.1.25

(I've reverted the test site.)

Can anyone suggest a fix to help me upgrade - which will hopefully fix the problem?

Thanks in advance, Chris

Comment: This seems to be a 'me too' Comment rather than an Answer.

Comment: thanks for making this more of an Answer

Comment: I've now updated civicrm to 5.67.0 and reverted PHP back to 8.1.25.  Everything now seems back to normal.  Scheduled jobs and scheduled reminders are working fine.  Thank you @chriscant  for your help in this.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to 5.66.1 appears to fix this issue, [see here](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4739).

Comment: Thank you Lars SG for this information.  I have temporarily gone back to using PHP v 8.0 and the issue I've been experiencing now seems to have gone away. I will try updating to CiviCRM v 5.66.1 shortly.

Comment: I've now updated civicrm to 5.67.0 and reverted PHP back to 8.1.25.  Everything now seems back to normal.  Scheduled jobs and scheduled reminders are working fine.  Thank you  @Lars SG for your help in this.