# Illegal argument error

Tags: profile, error, pear

Wordpress with php 8.1

Fatal error:  Uncaught IntlException: datefmt_create: invalid locale: U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR in /home/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/log/php-8.1-strftime.php:105

This give me an error for unable to reach the server if I want to modify or fill an event subscription form

further log informations

Stack trace:

```
#0 /home/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/log/php-8.1-strftime.php(105): IntlDateFormatter->__construct()

#1 /home/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/log/php-8.1-strftime.php(204): PHP81_BC\{closure}()

#2 [internal function]: PHP81_BC\{closure}()

#3 /home/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/log/php-8.1-strftime.php(185): preg_replace_callback()

#4 /home/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/log/Log.php(887): PHP81_BC\strftime()

#5 /home/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/log/Log/file.php(294): Log->formatTime()

#6 /home/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(601): Log_file->log()

#7 /home/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(573): CRM_Core_Error::debug_log_message()

#8 /home/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(442): CRM_Core_Error::debug_var()

#9 /home/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException()

#10 /home/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1199): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke()

#11 /home/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke()

#12 /home/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(334): WP_Hook->apply_filters()

#13 /home/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()

#14 /home/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action()

#15 {main}
  thrown in /home/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/log/php-8.1-strftime.php on line 105
```

Thank you for help

Comment: //    return (new IntlDateFormatter($locale, $date_type, $time_type, $tz, $calendar, $pattern))->format($timestamp);

after commented this line in /civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/log/php-8.1-strftime.php the form works, perhaps this is a bug

Comment: See https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45781/scheduled-jobs-stopped-working

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's a problem with php 8.1.25. See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4739